# Touchscreen woes on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, icons, 22.04, touchscreen, drag-and-drop

I installed 22.04 some days ago on a new Dell 5430 rugged laptop, which features a touchscreen. These two are the desired goals:

1. correct behaviour dragging with pen/finger systemwide (all app windows and icons on desktop)
2. enabling systemwide gestures to scroll documents/web/etc. with a stroke for all apps

PROBLEM ONE

Concerning behaviour, something's not right: some apps work correctly (e.g. gedit) which means I can drag and drop (move) them by using pen or finger on titlebar, also I can use the pen to select text or type (with on-screen keyboard) in them.

Problems arise when I use some apps, especially FIREFOX: firefox window does not move when I try (both with finger and pen) to drag its titlebar; I thought this problem was due to firefox being a snap, but I disinstalled the snap, then installed the original program from Mozilla and still nothing changed. Of course the mouse/trackpad always works 100%.

This problem also happens with iridium browser (installed from fedora rpm through alien), while does not happen with chromium browser from snaps.

ALSO, with the touchscreen I cannot drag&drop any icon over the DESKTOP (nor select it with a rectangle) neither do it either from NAUTILUS or from NEMO (this annoys me even more), but I can click over them with success.

PROBLEM TWO

Scrolling up and down is very important and I would like to do it with pen/finger. Now, most apps do this correctly like: nemo, nautilus (although they don't allow drag&drop!), gedit, evince, etc.

Especially FIREFOX, instead, never does this (while iridium this time does, as well as chromium). I tried to install EASYSTROKE and configure it, but nothing changed, so I purged it. The only thing I noticed is that, since easystroke had been installed, the drag&drop situation on the desktop worsened (I'm not 100% sure but recall that before I could maybe move icons).

QUESTIONS

Much part of the woes seems tied to firefox, which in its about:config section under browser.gestures offers some undocumented choices but not an option to try to disable its internal gestures system; do you have any experience on how to iron firefox up correctly in this regard?

I don't know what easystroke might have changed but I'd still like to move icons on desktop with the pen; is there any setting advice to follow? In dconf-editor I have found sections for mouse, touchpad, trackball, etc. but nothing about touchscreen and its effects over desktop/windows.

Thanks
Pasha

Comment: I don't think Easystroke has been supported for quite a while, and probably certainly not on 22.04. Disable it and see if your problems go away.

Comment: Thanks for your remark; I disabled it and the story is the same. Mostly browsers, especially firefox, are not reacting correctly to touchscreen, as described.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and see if the problem shows up there. Report back.

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay. I tried with Ubuntu live as asked.
Results are pretty much the *same*. Here some detail:


-gedit: can move window, can scroll contents
-libreoffice:  can move window, CANNOT scroll contents
-firefox:  CANNOT move window, CANNOT scroll contents

I thinks there's something wrong in 22.04 config.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X11/Xorg?

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then check at the Dell website for a newer BIOS.

Comment: Hi, here is wayland used. Just updated from 1.6.0 to latest 1.7.0 bios. Behaviour didn't change, same stuff. I think that if it were because of hardware/firmware no program would behave correctly, while many do. It just some who don't like firefox and partly libreoffice. I think there must be some setting to tweak but I have no idea where (as mentioned, in dconf-editor there is no touchscreen section).

Comment: Try switching to X11/Xorg and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: How do I make it?

Comment: Log out of your current session in Ubuntu. At the login screen, select your username, and in the lower-right corner of the screen you'll see an icon. Select it, note what the current setting is, then change it to Ubuntu on X11/xorg, then enter your password to finish logging in. Then retest Firefox, etc.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hi I took the time to make a thorough test, here are results:

Comment: UBUNTU 22.04 XORG: same as wayland, but worse, as gedit still scrolls but window does not move anymore (it moves some pixels and then stops)

Comment: KALI 2022.2: something better, in kali firefox window moves; no scroll both for libreoffice and firefox (pen highlights text, so I'm thinking this must be a "feature")

Comment: PartedMagic 2022_03_28 (slackware based): worse than ubuntu, cannot move any window

Comment: REMMINA windows RDP session under 22.04: can move any window on windows, firefox, libreoffice, editor; scroll in firefox/libreoffice still highlights text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this in the terminal and after you will need to log out and then back in to "apply" the changes.

```
echo export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/use-xinput2.sh
```

Comment: Hello Mason! You are a G.E.N.I.O.U.S.! Problem solved! Too bad you are on the other side of the ocean otherwise I would have called you for a beer! Thanks again mate!